# How to display total count number for each column in matplotlib bar chart for multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sample data
ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 47, 'Amanda Doe': 27, 'Maria Doe': 26}
non_ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 105, 'Amanda Doe': 64, 'Maria Doe': 48}
month="Apr-2020"
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.bar(X-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))
plt.xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
plt.title("Emails Closed per team member in {}".format(month) , fontsize=17)
plt.savefig('img.png')
plt.show()
```

My bar chart currently:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

I was trying the following:

```
#sample data
ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 47, 'Amanda Doe': 27, 'Maria Doe': 26}
non_ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 105, 'Amanda Doe': 64, 'Maria Doe': 48}
month="Apr-2020"

x = np.arange(len(month))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
rects2 = ax.bar(X-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('# Requests')
ax.set_title("Emails Closed per team member in {}".format(month) , fontsize=17)
ax.set_xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
ax.set_xticklabels(month)
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))


def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However there is a problem as it won't display the user name (John Doe etc) but 'p' or 'r' etc. See below:

[image]

Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.set_xticklabels(month)` should be replaced by  `ax.set_xticklabels(ME_Requests.keys())`.

To have the labels just between the bars, you could subtract `width/2` from `X` for the left bars, and add `width/2` to `X` for the right bars. To remove the ticks marks, `ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)` could be used.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 47, 'Amanda Doe': 27, 'Maria Doe': 26}
non_ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 105, 'Amanda Doe': 64, 'Maria Doe': 48}
month = "Apr-2020"
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(X + 0.1, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
rects2 = ax.bar(X - 0.1, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests', 'non_ME_Requests'))
ax.set_xticks(X)
ax.set_xticklabels(ME_Requests.keys())
ax.set_title(f"Emails Closed per team member in {month}", fontsize=17)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)

def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate(f'{height:.0f}',
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: result]